# Unity3d iOS c++ native library plugin. How to?

Tags: c++, ios, plugins, unity-game-engine

I'm using [this](http://google.github.io/liquidfun/) c++ particle physics library in my game. So far I have it working in unity on android and windows.
I'm now looking into getting it working on iOS and it seems like quite a daunting task.
The library is a superset of Box2D so it is quite a large complex library.
Here is my idea for tackling this, I'm hoping someone with some experience can say if they think this might work, or if not suggest a better way of doing it.

My idea is to..
Use Unitys 'Automated plugin integration' where you add your .cpp and .h source files to the Assets\Plugins\iOS folder and it sym links them in the xcode project (whatever that means)
The problem here is that subfolders are not supported so I would have to flatten the directory structure of the Box2D project and put everything in one folder. My idea is to do this using a python script that will change all the include statements in the source code so for example..

```
   #include <Box2D/Common/b2Settings.h>
```

would be changed to..

```
   #include <b2Settings.h>
```

Is there a reason this would not work?

Comment: What's stopping you from actually executing the python script and seeing what happens?

Comment: I definitely will do that. I just wanted to check how doomed poeple think it is before I waste time on it, or whether there is a better way (from someone whos got a native c++ library working in unity in iOS before). I think this idea is kinda crazy, also I have seen reports here (from 2013) that unities  'Automated plugin integration' for iOS is broken after unity 4

Comment: I think your biggest concern regarding what you are trying to do is performance, regardless of whether the Automated plugin integration works or not. And the best way to see that, is to actually do it and profile it. If it works, performs well and does the job, it's not crazy ;)

Comment: @GuyeIncognito Do you mind helping me with figuring out what you figured out on my thread post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68272983/how-to-add-native-ios-framework-plugin-to-unity3d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So that crazy idea actually worked! The performance was terrible on an iphone 4 but absolutely flawless on a iphone 5. The only other issue I had was I had to turn

```
   #include <Box2D/Common/b2Settings.h>
```

into

```
   #include  "b2Settings.h"
```

Xcode didnt like the pointy brackets.
Also this failed to build on the simulator but worked on an actual device